# Finch: how to remap modkey to ctrl

Tags: pidgin

I am desperately trying to remap the default mod-key <kbd>Alt</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd> using finch.
What do I need to add to `.gntrc` for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool named as Xcape which can you that required functionality.

**Installation**

open your terminal and type as

```
 sudo apt-get install git gcc make libx11-dev libxtst-dev pkg-config
 mkdir xcape
 cd xcape
 git clone https://github.com/alols/xcape.git .
 make
```

**Usage:**
After installing it all you need to do is simply this in your terminal.
for shifting <kbd>Alt</kbd> into <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

```
xcape -e 'Alt_L=Ctrl_L'
```

Then logout/restart to apply the changes and then you see the changes.

Hope that helps.